# Using the matrix in different dimensions

Tags: matlab, matrix, reshape, dimension

I have a matrix with the dimension `65536x2` which I want to use with another of dimension `256x256`. How can I change the first matrix dimension to be `256x256`? I tried `reshape` as follows:

```
 N=reshape(u,256,256);
```

But, got the following error:

```
Error using reshape
To RESHAPE the number of elements must not change.
```

What should I do in this case?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

The original question mentioned `1x65536`, but realized that it should be `65536x2`

Comment: use debugger: `>> dbstop if error` and verify that `numel(u)` indeed is 65536.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `N = reshape(u, 256, [])` and then  verify that `size(N)` is `256 x 256`. This syntax for `reshape` automatically sizes the dimension specified by `[]` to whatever it needs to be to fit the number of elements in the array.

**EDIT:** My own attempt at reshaping a random `1 x 65536` matrix into a `256 x 256` matrix did not have a problem with either syntax, so I would suggest you verify that your initial matrix is in fact `1 x 65536` as well.

Comment: Note that it will only work if `numel(u)` is a multiple of 256.

Comment: @Engineero. You are right. I noticed that the matrix size is `65536 x2`. In this case, can I still `reshape` it?

Comment: Yes, you would just end up with a `256 x 512` matrix using the `reshape(u, 256, [])` command.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot `reshape` 65536-by-2 array into 256-by-256 you have "extra" 65536 elements...

try

```
>> reshape( u, 256, 256 ,[] );
```